# How can I find pKa from a titration curve?

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry

I am fully aware that the pKa is the pH at half the equivalence point, but are there some programs or methods I could use to accurately estimate the pKa without manually drawing lines on the graph?

Comment: If you are titrating by hand, I'm afraid that there is no way out. You'll have to draw a graph.

Comment: Have you tried any curve fitting solution (Excel, Igor, Origin..)?